# xcode6 launch image-assets catalogue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6

In order to let our universal app to fit to all devices,so that same images of `iPhone6` will be scaled  on `iPhone5` to look the same ,we have added to the project the default launch images,

```
Default-568h@2x
Default-667h@2x
Default-736h@3x
```

but the simulator does not scale the images on `iPhone5` ,so they look **good** on the `iPhone6` ,but on 5 they cover each other ,because there is no scaling.

I was told to also set them in the `assets catalogue` in order for the iPhone5 to *scale* the app images.

But when you open the assets catalogue, you dont have a placeholder for all the above default images i showed here (for iphone5 , 6, 6+) , but just:
`iphone portrait(retina and 2x)` , and `iPad portrait and landscape`.

1. where do you set the `Default-568h@2x` and `Default-667h@2x` and `Default-736h@3x`??
2. could that be the reason why the `iPhone5` is not scaling our app assets ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look, you should open attribute inspector, choose options, which you wanna support, then just drag images with required resolution, when you use assets catalogue, names of images are not important, name them as you wish.
[image]

Comment: oh great that worked, thanks very much ! could this be the problem why i didn't get the scaling on the iPhone5 ? why just putting the images in the project will not work ?

Comment: still strange that in landscape iOS8 you dont have the iPhone5 and 6

Comment: Earlier I faced the similar issue and the solution was to use assets catalogue. I did not bother my head with investigating the root reason, because I liked new instrument :)